# Tkinter layout designer

Tags: tkinter

I am fairly new to tkinter and I am making a project with it. But the trouble is that I am unable to properly place widgets where I want them to be.

Since I am new, I end up sticking all widgets to one end or using grid which often looks awkward.

Is there any online/offline app/website which allows you to drag and drop widgets and tells you which layout manager to use and their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this drag and Drop GUI generator for python

Download and install ActiveTCL and page.exe for Python GUI generator.

https://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/